# "Unable to open the database file : "

Tags: esri-geodatabase, arcgis-runtime

I am trying to test the ArcGIS map to see if it fits the needs of my app. Unfortunately I have encountered a problem when trying to read a geodatabase created with ArcCatalog or a sample downloaded from the internet. I have tried with a developer licence and Basic license but both return the same error.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.1 for Desktop and ArcGIS 10.2.5 Runtime for .NET

The error is: 
`Unable to open the database file`

and it is thrown on line :

```
Geodatabase geodatabase = await Geodatabase.OpenAsync(@"{path}\db.gdb");
```

StackTrace:

```
StackTrace  
"  at RuntimeCoreNet.Interop.HandleException(Boolean retVal)\r\n   
at RuntimeCoreNet.CoreFeatureCache..ctor(String databasePath)\r\n  
at Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Data.Geodatabase..ctor(String path)\r\n  
at Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Data.Geodatabase.OpenAsync(String path)\r\n  
at SmartAssArcGISWPF.MainWindow.<MyMapView_Loaded>d__0.MoveNext() in.... 
string
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem and found a solution?

The licence for Developer is supposed to contain all functionality, is this one with geodatabase not included?

Comment: Is the downloaded file a valid file geodatabase? That doesn't look like a license error --it looks like a "corrupt input" error.

Comment: Are you trying to open a Geodatabase built by a more modern version of arcgis?

Comment: @Vince ArcCatalog can open the gdb, both the one I created and the sample I downloaded from the internet. I does not look like a corrupt file.

Comment: @Hornbydd I am using ArcGIS 10.2.1 for Desktop and ArcGIS 10.2.5 Runtime for .NET

Comment: Please do not bury important details in the comments -- *edit* the question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you generating a Runtime Geodatabase, or are you trying to open a File Geodatabase? (File geodatabases are not supported)

See https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/guide/create-an-offline-map.htm for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying to open a geodatabase.